# Indexes no Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, índices

Estou iniciando os estudos com os índices. Tenho uma base no MongoDB onde os documentos tem cerca de 10 campos. As pesquisas podem ser feitas usando todas essas variáveis.

Criei um index com todos os campos, e pensei que iria funcionar ok, mas sempre recebo um alerta de "slow query".

Eu preciso criar indexes para todas as combinações de campos? Alguns desses vão estar em todas as queries.

Qual a melhor estratégia para criar esses indexes? `{a:1, b:1}, {a:1, b:1, c:1}...`

Um exemplo de documento no banco (apenas os campos que podem ser filtrados):

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "objectivo": 1,
    "tipo": 1,
    "preco": 50000,
    "num_quartos": 2,

    "estado": "São Paulo",
    "cidade": "São Paulo",
    "endereco": "Rua...",
    "referencia": "12345",
    "updated": 1
}
```

Comment: Seria bom voce postar como voce fez seu index e um exemplo da sua colecao(tabela) assim fica mais facil de obter uma resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resposta curta para tua pergunta:** sim, cada combinação precisa de um índice.

Considerações:

- Considera a ordem em que os campos são passados na consulta. Um índice `{a:1,b:1}` é diferente de um índice `{b:1,a:1}`.
- Para **criar o índice** considera os seguintes recomendações:

  - Primeiro usa os campos de igualdade/diferença (que você use filtro direto de um valor).
  - Depois considera a ordenação que você usa na consulta.
  - E por último considera intervalos.
  - Dessa forma você facilita o trabalho do otimizador, e se todos os campos que você retorna estiverem no índice o banco nem acessa a tabela somente o índice.

Se você tem uma consulta com o seguinte filtro `{preco: { $gt: 3250}, cidade:"São Paulo"}` ordenando por `{num_quartos: -1}` a criação do índice ficaria `{cidade: 1, num_quartos: -1, preco: 1}`. Nota que na consulta a ordem não importa, mas no índice faz muita diferença.

Você pode criar alguns índices com o que sabe/supõe que vai ser pesquisado. A longo prazo a melhor abordagem seria monitorar as consultas que são feitas com mais frequência, e para essas adicionar índices específicos. Assim você faz o balanceamento do trabalho do banco para manter os índices e a utilização real deles.